# API methods must wait until critical method is done

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have MVC API controller.
One method in this controller is critical.
This mean that all other API methods must wait util this method is done.

My basic idea is to block threads in constructor.
But I am not sure if this is so smart?

```
public class TestApi : Controller
{
    private static bool wait = false;
    public TestApi()
    {
        // wait if critical method is working.
        while (wait)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void PostCriticalMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            wait = true;
            // do critical work
        }
        finally
        {
            wait = false;
        }
    }
    // Many non critical API methods...
}
```

Solution two:

```
 public class TestApi : Controller
    {
        private static bool wait = false;
        private static AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        public TestApi()
        {
            // wait if critical method is working.
            if (wait) waitHandle.WaitOne();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public void PostCriticalMethod()
        {
          try
          {
            wait = true;
            // do critical work
          }
          finally {
            waitHandle.Set();
            wait = false;
          } 
        }           
        // Many non critical API methods...
    }
```

Comment: If you need this in an api, then in my opinion it would need a rethinking of the design. Api's are not supposed to work like this. Why do you need this? If you tell your challenge instead of your solution maybe we can help better.

Comment: I have API which task is to restore database. Other API methods must wait until database is restored.

Comment: Disadvantage of this approach is that DB restoration will begin when first API request is created (request on that Controller), and that is too late I think. The first client requesting the API will be blocked for sure and other callers too (as long as the restore process takes). Better approach will be to run this `restoration task` during the WEB startup

Comment: User should be able to restore database manually from client application.

Comment: If you are going to block use WaitOne() : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Something like my solution two?

Comment: How long does the restore take? And how long is the client going to wait (before time-out)?

Comment: Everything will be finished soon enough. Time out is not problem.

Comment: _But I am not sure if this is so smart?_ You have working solution and asking for "better" approach. It is obviously opinion based, because there can be implemented a bunch of solutions. With same result - your API need to have a state - some "global"(shared between all controllers) and thread-safe information `IsDatabasesRestored`.

Comment: I don't like solution with infinite loop - while(true) - this is why I am asking for smarter solution - to wait until work is done.

Comment: If client will be able to define his own Timeout for requests - then you need provide some documentation about minimum value of timeout can be used

Comment: Agree for the first solution - it just a waste of thread and processor time. What you think about your second solution?

Comment: Is it possible that client will execute "RestoreDatabase" twice? If so  - then you need to wait when other executing requests will finish before starting restoring

Comment: Restore will be done once a year (or never :)). But still must work. I have to test second solution. I never before used AutoResetEvent .

Comment: What about this: set a flag that the api is busy, and every time a request comes in while the flag is set you return an error response with statuscode 500 or 503 with the reason that a blocking operation is in progress. That way you won't block clients and you don't have to have a blocking mechanism in the controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution (This is async version, but non async is even simpler):

In base class (common for all controllers) I add method BlockOtherRequestsBeforeExecute

```
        private static readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphoreInit = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

        protected async Task BlockOtherRequestsBeforeExecute(Func<Task> criticalAction)
        {
            await semaphoreInit.WaitAsync();
            try
            {
                await criticalAction();
            }
            finally
            {
                semaphoreInit.Release();
            }
        }
```

Then I can call method in secure way if I need to:

```
await BlockOtherRequestsBeforeExecute(async () => await RestoreDatabase());
```

Important part is that `semaphoreInit` must be used in all critical places.
This can be done in constructor of base class, and then all API-s are blocked until critical action is not finished.